# How to plan an afternoon with n games (1 vs 1) and 2n players

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

This question was asked by a friend of mine who is a teacher in elementary school, they want to plan an afternoon of games.

There are *n* games (1vs1) and *2n* players (n=12 for the IRL problem).
Each round, each game is played by 2 players.
At the end of the round, the places are changed so that 2 given players meet only once and a player does not play the same game twice.
We want all players to play each games.

The last two constraints imply that there are exactly *n* rounds.

### We can see that n=2 as no solution.

Players are noted with numbers and game with capital letters.

- Round1: A:1vs2, B:3vs4
- Round2: A:only 3 and 4 can play but they have already met.

### While n=3 is possible

- Round1: A:1vs2, B:3vs4, C:5vs6
- Round2: A:3vs5, B:1vs6, C:2vs4
- Round3: A:4vs6, B:2vs5, C:1vs3

### Actual question n=12

I tried a lot of things, my best results come from a brut force algorithm that try to fill the matrix with elements from a randomly shuffled list of all 276 possibles pairs of players :

```
00: A:02|23 B:08|20 C:09|15 D:00|12 E:05|06 F:13|19 G:07|17 H:11|22 I:10|21 J:03|04 K:14|16 L:01|18
01: A:08|12 B:07|23 C:02|16 D:01|13 E:00|04 F:03|05 G:21|22 H:09|18 I:06|17 J:19|20 K:10|15 L:11|14
02: A:13|16 B:02|19 C:07|20 D:08|10 E:09|11 F:15|23 G:12|18 H:00|17 I:01|22 J:06|14 K:04|05 L:03|21
03: A:03|19 B:15|16 C:08|13 D:05|20 E:07|14 F:10|18 G:04|09 H:01|02 I:11|12 J:17|21 K:22|23 L:00|06
04: A:10|22 B:04|11 C:03|17 D:16|23 E:12|19 F:02|14 G:00|13 H:06|20 I:15|18 J:01|05 K:09|21 L:07|08
05: A:11|20 B:13|21 C:19|23 D:02|22 E:15|17 F:06|16 G:03|10 H:07|12 I:05|09 J:00|18 K:01|08 L:__|__
06: A:06|07 B:14|18 C:01|11 D:15|19 E:20|22 F:00|21 G:02|08 H:10|16 I:04|23 J:12|13 K:__|__ L:05|17
07: A:18|21 B:05|22 C:00|10 D:03|09 E:01|23 F:08|11 G:14|19 H:04|13 I:07|16 J:02|15 K:17|20 L:__|__
08: A:05|14 B:03|12 C:06|21 D:07|18 E:10|13 F:01|20 G:11|16 H:08|15 I:00|02 J:09|23 K:__|__ L:19|22
09: A:01|17 B:09|10 C:12|22 D:11|21 E:02|03 F:04|07 G:05|23 H:__|__ I:13|14 J:08|16 K:06|18 L:15|20
10: A:04|15 B:01|06 C:05|18 D:14|17 E:16|21 F:09|22 G:__|__ H:03|23 I:08|19 J:10|11 K:07|13 L:02|12
11: A:00|09 B:__|__ C:04|14 D:__|__ E:08|18 F:12|17 G:01|15 H:05|21 I:03|20 J:07|22 K:11|19 L:13|23
```

Comment: This is equivalent to [a question asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4527701). In the question, read the diagram as follows: the red vertices are games, the blue vertices are rounds, and the pair of numbers on a line from red to blue says which two players are playing that game on that round. The answer gives the same information in an $n\times n$ grid, where you can say that the rows are rounds and the columns are games (or vice versa).

Comment: This question could be clearer on the specific point: is the number of *games* required to match the number of players? There's a three-round solution with $4$ players if we don't mind one table sitting empty each round.

Comment: @EricSnyder, you are right, it's a good solution to ease things. But it turn out it's only relevant for n=2 (see Misha Lavrov comment on my answer below).

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [Misha Lavrov in his comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528865/how-to-plan-an-afternoon-with-n-games-1-vs-1-and-2n-players?noredirect=1#comment9517251_4528865), this question is related to the [Graeco-Latin squares (or mutual orthogonal latin squares a.k.a. MOLS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares) that are known to have a solution for any *n* except 2 and 6.

Given a MOLS, first split the players in two set of *n* players (the Latins and the Graecos).
The players are deduced by mapping the two value in a case to the two corresponding player (one from each set).¹

MOLS for n=12 are known to exist, but I can't find one on the internet (n=10 is very popular).
[R have a function for this](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/blocksdesign/html/GraecoLatin.html), I may install it anytime soon.

1). We can deduce from this that the members of the same set never play with each other. Does this mean that n=6 is possibly solvable if we allow this ?

Comment: I also noticed that it's hard to find some Greco-Latin squares on the internet. So I added a page on my website which gives examples for $n \le 24$: https://misha.fish/squares/. This gives a solution for $n=12$. Also, since $n=6$ doesn't have a Greco-Latin square, I instead included a $6 \times 6$ grid that mixes the Latin and Greek letters, which is actually just as good for the problem we want to solve here.

Comment: Wow! Thanks, you give me peace of mind before the night, the possibility of a mixed 6x6 was stuck in my mind. That is also a proof that this problem is a relaxed version of the MOLS problem. Can you please give your method to generate the 6x6 mixed solution? I'm also curious what software or programming language you are using ?

Comment: I was using some home-brewed simulated annealing in Mathematica. Some similar Mathematica code for a different problem is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3039798).

Comment: @MishaLavrov You may want to post a link to the "quantum" solution for $6 \times 6$. Also, you mention being able to do more than two alphabets... you could always use colors! I believe Wikipedia has an example using colors, words instead of letters, and word *length*.